# How do I replace the audio in an MP4 file without re-encoding?

Tags: windows, audio, mp4, video-encoding

I've got a video in an MP4 container that I would like to **replace** the audio track in (**not** [add another audio stream to](https://superuser.com/questions/53782/how-do-i-add-another-audio-stream-to-an-mp4-file), nor [convert the audio format of](https://superuser.com/questions/331717/how-do-i-convert-the-format-of-an-audio-track-inside-an-mp4-video)).

Someone elsewhere online suggested to use VirtualDub to replace the audio track, but it wouldn't even open up the video file. [Journeyman Geek suggested in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9702593#9702593) that I use `ffmpeg`, but the documentation is pretty difficult for me to understand.

How can I accomplish this on Windows? I'll download/install external programs if I must.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I ended up scrutinizing the documentation for `ffmpeg` and worked out a solution:

> `ffmpeg.exe -i input_video.mp4 -i replacement_audio.m4a -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4`

Comment: RTFM strikes again!

Comment: Note that this does not preserve all metadata, such as 360 equirectangular (I haven't tested the extent).

Answer (score 14):

An addition to the current solution: If the audio file does not match the video container's format, just avoid the -acodec parameter:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input_video.mp4 -i replacement_audio.m4a -vcodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 output.mp4
```

Now, only the audio gets encoded in order to match the container.

Answer (score 3):

There are several free software for this:

- [MP4Box GUI](http://www.videohelp.com/software/My-MP4Box-GUI)
- [MKVTOOLKIT](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html)
- [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/)

and many others at videohelp.com

Comment: MP4Box seems very simple and I didn't find any option to replace audio, but MKVToolNix GUI is easy to understand and does a great job!

Comment: I confirm that MKVToolNix works to merge video and audio without re-encoding, and also it allows to set a delay for the audio. It's available on Linux, MacOSX and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one mentioned [onlineconverter.com](https://www.onlineconverter.com/). In addition to many other goodies, their site allows to [add or replace audio in a video file](https://www.onlineconverter.com/add-audio-to-video).

Trying it out, replacing the audio in a sample video file does *not* seem to affect the video.